# p:calendar AJAX updates only the second time

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with PrimeFaces calendar and ajax update.

I have a calendar and when I change the date on the UI I want to refresh another component. The problem is that the first time I change the date, the other component stays the same, but when i change the date a second time, the other component is updated with the correct value that I am expecting.

Here is my form:

```
<h:form>
    <p:calendar
        value="#{foo.dtValidade}">
        <p:ajax update="criteriosDataGridTeste" event="dateSelect"
            listener="#{foo.updateTeste}" />
    </p:calendar>

    <h:panelGroup id="criteriosDataGridTeste">
        <td><h:selectOneMenu value="#{foo.idtpresult}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="ok" itemValue="ok" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="not ok" itemValue="not ok" />
            </h:selectOneMenu></td>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

I am using primefaces 3.0.1

By debugging I found out that the listener is being called before the value `dtValidade` is set.

But i thought it should be the other way.
Why is this happening?

A simplified version of my bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "foo")
@ViewScoped
public class Foooo {

    private Date dtValidade;
    private String idtpresult;

    public Foooo() {
        dtValidade = new Date();
        idtpresult = "not ok";
    }


    public Date getDtValidade() {
        return dtValidade;
    }

    public void setDtValidade(Date dt) {
        this.dtValidade = dt;
    }


    public String getIdtpresult() {
        return idtpresult;
    }

    public void setIdtpresult(String idtpresult) {
        this.idtpresult = idtpresult;
    }

    public void updateTeste() {
        Date now = new Date();
        if (dtValidade.before(now)) {
            idtpresult = "ok";
        } else {
            idtpresult = "not ok";
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, update your question with the related java code and the other component.

Comment: Better yet, make it an [mcve]

Comment: I think this is **not** an [mcve]. Removing the selectOneMenu and graphicImage in the datatable makes it work? If not, remove them. And your listener? It won't compile. It is not a managedbean, java class nothing. And your xhtml misses a lot, this won't work. And your listener wont be called at all since its method signature is wrong, not even the second time, so please, please, please make it an [mcve]  and see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: It is weird. The date value should update before the listener invocation, and then in the listener you read the selected date. Also, in your initial answer wasn't the update field dynamic?

Comment: No it wasn't @lametaweb. i also think this is weird, maybe the problem is somewhere else. I'm trying to find out what can be...

Comment: See the last sentence of my previous comment... We should not be guessing etc...  I'd like to try to reproduce...

Comment: I have reproduced your code, a simplified version, and the behaviour is the expected: First the update and then the method call. Write a minimal example in your page,  without entities or conditions, and comment the result.

Comment: By chance I had an openned tab in my browser with your old initial answer, and the update attribute was dynamic: <p:ajax **update="#{tabId}:criteriosDataGrid"** event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.updateFinancasCriteria}"/>. Does it remain dynamic now?

Comment: Oh that, sorry, #{tabId} is passed as parameter. This calendar is in a xhtml included in two different pages and depending on the page, the `criteriosDataGrid` component is child of different components with different id. But this is working, because i use it in other components and also in this case but only for the second time i change the date

Comment: @lametaweb i also tried to put the calendar on the main xhtml but the problem maintains.

Comment: Doesn't it a normal ajax JSF cycle?

Comment: i have reproduced this exact code in my project and the result is the same.
Can this be some configuration problem? A primefaces version bug?

Comment: Anybody knows if `dateselect` is the only event we can choose in calendar ajax?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
add in xhtml code in the h:form where yours calendar is

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="criteriosDataGrid" >
```

and in your ajax

```
<p:ajax
    event="dateSelect" listener="#{foo.updateCriteria}" oncomplete="rc"/>
```

i dont know excatly if you need the rest of attributes of p:ajax

Comment: Why would this be needed, a duplicate update? It seems illogical and hence an explanation would be in place. And if it works, it is a workaround that should not be needed. The real cause is something else, but that is impossible to tell if the OP does not post an [mcve]

Comment: ive removed update. This is why because when ajax event triggered foo.cumpLegal.dtEmissao isnt not updated. When the ajax event finished primefaces updated the values in bean. Then oncomplete i invoke remotecommand.